# How to retrieve objectID from within a class on parse server using swift

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, cloud

Alright so i'm starting to get a headache here... Once my user sign onto my app i create a new class on parse with the name `PFUser.Current()?.objectId!` Within this class i store all the users information, and the user can acces it from any device since his user ID never changes. One of the things i store in the user class is an array which leads me to my question: I want to be able to acces this array but the only way this can be done is by using:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "\(PFUser.current()?.objectId!)") // Calling the user class
    query.getObjectInBackground(withId: "") { (object: PFObject?, error: Error?) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)

        } else {

            print(object)
        }
    }
```

The Problem is that i do not know how to retrieve the objectID from within the class UserObjectID.

I found some code that lets me retrieve my user list and append usernames and iDs to an array:

```
var query = PFUser.query()

    query?.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in

        if let users = objects {

            for object in users {

                if let user = object as? PFUser {

                self.usernames.append(user.username!)
                self.userids.append(user.objectId!)

                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

How can i do a similar search, and find all the objectIDs within my individual userClass instead of the superUser class?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to create a new class for each user?  you going to end up with an enormous amount of tables with 1 row in each.  Best to add your array as a column in the current _User table or create a new table and save all user arrays in it with a pointer.

That being said if do and your new table is named from the objectId of the user then you should be able to query that class with:

```
var userId: String = ""

let userClassName = PFUser.current()!.objectId!

let query = PFQuery(className: userClassName)
// as there is only 1 row get the first
query.getFirstObjectInBackground { (object, error) in
    if error != nil || object == nil {
        print("nothing here try again")
    } else {
        userId = object?.objectId
    }
}
```

If you have a table with many users and a pointer then use the following lines as a guide

```
let userObjectId =  PFUser.current()!.objectId!
query.whereKey("yourPointerName", equalTo: PFObject(outDataWithClassName: "theClassYouWantToQuery", objectId: userObjectId))
```